# Cannot query existing Ignite cache using SQL tooling

Tags: java, sql, caching, ignite, dbeaver

I am trying to query an Apache Ignite cache (version 2.2) ,which I have created via a Java script:

```
    TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
    TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder=new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
    List<String> adresses=new ArrayList<String>();
    adresses.add("127.0.0.1:48500..48520");
    ipFinder.setAddresses(adresses);
    spi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);

    IgniteConfiguration cfg=new IgniteConfiguration().setDiscoverySpi(spi).setClientMode(true);

    CacheConfiguration cache_conf=new CacheConfiguration<String,Custom_Class>().setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED).setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC).setBackups(1).
            setIndexedTypes(String.class,Custom_Class.class).setName("Spark_Ignite");

    Ignite ignite=Ignition.getOrStart(cfg);

    ignite.getOrCreateCache(cache_conf);

    System.out.println("[INFO] CACHE CREATED");
    ignite.close();
```

I am using DBeaver to perform a simple SQL query to this cache.

The problem is, when I try to do a query, I get this error:

```
SELECT * FROM Custom_Class;

 Table "Custom_Class" not found; SQL statement:SELECT * FROM Custom_Class
```

Same if I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Spark_Ignite;

 Table "Spark_Ignite" not found; SQL statement:SELECT * FROM Spark_Ignite
```

However, if I follow the instructions mentioned here: https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/sql-tooling , I get the query results with no issue.

I ran ignitevisor.sh,and indeed all the caches are there, and all of them have records:

[image]

What might be wrong here?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Using the quotes as mentioned in the answer I was able to query the table, but it shows no records, while ignitevisor shows 63.
 This is the script I use for the class:

```
public class Custom_Class implements Serializable {
@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private String a;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private String b;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private String c;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private String d;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private String e;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private String f;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private String g;

@QuerySqlField(index = true)
private String h;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to be able to use cache with SQL, it needs to be either:

- Created using `CREATE TABLE` DML. In this case, schema is PUBLIC, which is usually the default.
- Have `indexedTypes` specified in its `cacheConfiguration`, along with annotations on those types. In this case, schema is `"cacheName"`, quotes matter, and table name is `VALUETYPEINCAPS`. If key is primitive type its field name is `_key`, if value is primitive it will be `_val`, they are excluded from `*`.
- Have `queryEntities` specified in its `cacheConfiguration`. In this case, you can specify table name and column names for primitive types, but schema is `"cacheName"`.

If cache was created without SQL support, you can't add it other than by destroying and recreating cache.

I can see your cache have indexed types. Now, how about:

```
INSERT INTO "Spark_Ignite".CUSTOM_CLASS(_key, id) VALUES ('foo', 1);
SELECT _key, * FROM "Spark_Ignite".CUSTOM_CLASS;
```

You can also try invoking !tables in the `sqlline` tool that comes with Apache Ignite.

Comment: thanks, I will accept your answer. as putting the cache name inside "" worked, and I can query the cache. However for some reason all my records are blank, do you know why this might be? As the ignitevisor states, I should see 63 records

Comment: @manuelmourato this should be because your cache doesn't contain String to Custom_Class, but some other types. Double check the types. Does `INSERT` work?

Comment: I have created another question with the specifics on how I insert data to the cache, would be grateful if you took a look, thank you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49652724/sql-query-returns-empty-result-for-apache-ignite-cache

Answer (score 1):

You should either set `CacheConfiguration#sqlSchema` property to `PUBLIC`, or use a quoted name of the cache as a schema name in DBeaver.

Refer to the following page in the documentation for more information: https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/schema-and-indexes

Comment: I'm not actually sure you can set schema to `PUBLIC`. I remember this was a no-no.

Comment: @alamar, yes, you can. This is what I always do actually :)

Comment: @Denis, thank you for your answer, indeed it was the quotes that were missing. However, I don't see any records when I query, and it clearly says in ignitevisor that there are 63 records in that table, Do you know why this might be?

Comment: @manuelmourato Can you provide contents of your Custom_Class and code, that you use to populate the cache with data? I think, your issue could be caused by missing QuerySqlField annotations on the classes'  fields.

Comment: @Denis I've updated the question with the contents, but I made sure to add QuerySqlField before every field, so I dont belive that that is the problem...

Comment: @manuelmourato how do you populate the cache? If it contains objects of some type different than Custom_Class, then SQL won't show them.

Comment: @Denis, I have created another question with the specifics on how I populate the cache, thanks in advance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49652724/sql-query-returns-empty-result-for-apache-ignite-cache